# IOS :Get UIImage Orientation inside a UIImageview with exif data?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage, exif

I am rotating a `UIImageview` and the `UIImage` inside of it. I want to get the orientation of the `UIImage` after rotating the `UIImageview`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `myImage.imageOrientation`, which will give you the UIImageOrientation.

OR

If you used `UIImagePickerViewController` then use its delegate method

`"imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:"`

In This method you can also access  the **info dictionary**

```
NSlog(@"%d", [info objectForKey:@"Orientation"]);
```

Comment: Thanks @iPatel, But the thing is I want to get the exif data of the rotated image. How can I ensure that the exif data also changed with the orientation.